# Strict Standards: Declaration of JCacheControllerPage:

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

Need help on this problem. I received an error message

> Strict Standards: Declaration of JCacheControllerPage::store() should be compatible with JCacheController::store($data, $id, $group = NULL) in Unknown on line 0

but I don't know what caused this problem and how do I resolve it? I'm using joomla 2.5 and still learning how to make these things work.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the latest Joomla 2.5 version?  Strict Standards messages are not really errors and you can disable these errors by going to Joomla Global Configuration and set Error Reporting to Basic OR None for live sites and Maximum for sites under constructions.